# Returning an array of structure as Json Response using GO

Tags: json, struct, go

I am building a REST api in GO and I am able to fetch the JSON response from the server. I am looking forward to store the JSON response in sort of a container (array) and return that structure from the function. I have my data structures defined something like this -
{

```
type Payload struct {
    Stuff []Data `json:"data"`  // holds the JSON response returned
}

type Container struct {
    container []Payload
}

type ListContainersResponse struct {
    Data []Container    // want this thing to be returned from the function
}


func (client *Client) ListContainers() (ListContainersResponse, error) {
   // fetches the JSON response 
   var p Payload 

    // XYZ is something of the type ListContainersResponse which needs to be returned 
   return  XYZ
}
```

}

iterating over p gives me my JSON structure and I want to append it to a Data[] container which can hold this returned JSON response and returned back from the function. I tried playing around with it but get some exceptions. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks, I got my code working by doing something like this 
{

```
var result ListContainersResponse
    var temp Container
    temp.container = append(temp.container, p)
    result.Data = append(result.Data, temp)
```

}

Comment: You need to show an example of what you're trying to do. I don't know what `Data` is, or what errors you're getting.

Comment: So you have already decoded the json into an instance of Payload p?

Comment: Yeah i decoded the json into an instance of Payload p. Thanks i got it working. i'll share my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already got the JSON decoded into an instance of Payload p.

```
func (client *Client) ListContainers() (ListContainersResponse, error) {
   // fetches the JSON response 
   var p Payload 

   XYZ := ListContainersResponse {
       Data: []Container {
           container: []Payload {
               {p},
           },
       },
   }

   // XYZ is something of the type ListContainersResponse which needs to be returned 
   return XYZ
}
```

Additionally, in case any else is interested, here is how I would get the JSON into the struct:

```
var p Payload
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
err := decoder.Decode(&p)
```

Where `r` is of type `http.Request`.
I expect the json string looks something like:

```
{
    "data": [...]
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thanks. I did something like this to get my code working - { var result ListContainersResponse
 var temp Container
 temp.container = append(temp.container, p)
 result.Data = append(result.Data, temp)}